# Need help to call core fields(address,city, location..) in signup form of phpfox

Tags: phpfox

I know through custom fields we can add and assign the fields to registration form. But in that case its showing two times address,city etc. fields in user profile. Its happens because phpfox has address, city and so on fields in core product. So I need help to call that core product fields in signup form.....

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Go to AdminCP -> Settings -> Manage Settings -> Registration. You can choose which fields show up in the registration form there.